# Jersey MOXy JSON Case-Insensitive Unmarshalling

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0, moxy

I'm trying to setup a REST-service with Jersey 2.x that consumes a JSON-Response by POST using MOXy.

Everything works fine as long as all the JSON-attributes are named **exactly** like the properties in my POJO. Is there any way to configure MOXy so that it allows case-insensitive unmarshalling? For example: Match JSON-attribute "testid" to "TestID" in my POJO.

The POJO-Field is camel case, but the incoming JSON-Attribute could be in any case and my sevice should be able to process it nonetheless.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why is your pojo field not camel case?

Comment: The POJO-Field is camel case, but the incoming JSON-Attribute could be in any case and my sevice should be able to process it nonetheless.

Comment: I've never used Moxy, but I am fairly certain that it supports JAXB annotations (even for JSON). As such, you should be able to add `@XmlElement(name="testid")` to the getter for the field and have the mapping work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without defining a custom unmarshaller (or parsing directly from the `HttpServletRequest`) you can only define the expected key name, as pointed out in the comment of rmlan, with the `JAXB` annotation `@XmlElement(name="testid")`. However this will not protect your service from a JSON input with a key like "TestID" or "TESTID".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I'll switch to Jackson which provides case insensitive support (see [Link](http://mtyurt.net/2015/07/27/case-insensitive-deserialization-in/) ) - since these annoations are not enough.